# How to set filter on a field to get data within 24 hours?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

Hi I want to set  filter on field `date` where the value of date field should within 24 hours.

`<filter name="date" string="Scheduled Date" domain="[('date', '&gt;=', datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')),('date', '&lt;=', datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:23:59'))]"/>`

I tried this one, but this retrieves only the data where the date field contains today's date

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

With timedelta

```
<filter name="last" domain="[('date', '&gt;=', (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')), ('date', '&lt;=', datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))]"
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you can also use schedule action. Within scheduler action you can define you method with appropriate setting.